# Sorting C# List based on Dictionary elements

Tags: c#, list, sorting, dictionary

in my C# program I have a list, which I populate with Dictionary elements:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> mylist = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> d1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
d1.Add("val1", 1);
d1.Add("val2", 2);
d1.Add("val3", 3);
mylist.Add(d1);
Dictionary<string, object> d2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
d2.Add("val1", 4);
d2.Add("val2", 5);
d2.Add("val3", 6);
mylist.Add(d2);
Dictionary<string, object> d3 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
d3.Add("val1", 7);
d3.Add("val2", 8);
d3.Add("val3", 9);
mylist.Add(d3);
```

I would like to sort the list according to a certain element in the dictionary elements, e.g., sort the list according to the "val3" object in the dictionaries. I tried this:
    mylist.OrderBy(x => x["val3"]);
My list order was still the same. Any idea what I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: `OrderBy` will give you a new IEnumerabe ... try `mylist = mylist.OrderBy(..).ToList()`

Comment: 'Cause it's the right order. Try OrderByDescending. And 'yes', result of OrderBy is another IEnumarable with which you should operate.

Comment: As @ArtyomKharlamov said, the values you say are already in the order you want. Maybe you are expecting something else? Do you want to keep the dictionaries for the ordering? If not, you could use a SelectMany and then order by Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you haven't assigned the result that `OrdeyBy` returns. You can do:

```
mylist = mylist.OrderBy(x => x["val3"]).ToList();
```

This will order your elements, put them into a new list.

You can also do that without creating a new list, using [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
mylist.Sort((x,y) => ((IComparable)x["val3"]).CompareTo(y["val3"]));
```

Comment: wouldn't the Sort throw an exception because of the object?

Comment: @Gonzix you are right we need to cast it `IComparable`.